# Can install a GFCI outlet with only two wires in an old house?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, old-house

[image]I am working on trying to install an GFCI outlet/switch combo. I have 2 wires coming from the wall. A red and white. Can I make this work? All I see answers for is a 3 wire system

Comment: What was there before?

Comment: A single light switch

Comment: Can we get a photo of the contents of the box, with the existing switch pulled over and to the side (do NOT unhook everythigng)?  Was there a receptacle here previously or are you hoping to add one?  If you're going to change browsers or devices to post a photo, go back to the same browser you used to ask this question, and [create an account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts).  That will let you log in from different devices e.g. to post the photo.

Comment: Working on figuring out how to post picture.

Comment: The old existing wiring that the short pigtails are attached to looks to be pre-plastic insulation and likely in bad condition. This really calls for an electrician experienced with 100-year old wiring to evaluate and determine what is safe to keep. It may turn out to be fairly simple to run new Romex inside the wall from your panel or another outlet to create an outlet there.

Comment: Well I see the picture, but it's so dark that it defies my Photoshop technique of brightening it up.    I don't think further efforts along those lines will be productive given the age of the wiring, the wires we hope to see in the back of the box just aren't there.

Answer (score 4):

[Some details assume you are in North America. However, the general principles apply anywhere.]

If you previously had a switch and only two wires (not counted ground - green or bare), then no, you cannot add an outlet.

What you have is a switch loop - hot from the panel (via the outlet or light box) and switched hot back to the outlet or light. For the outlet, you also need a neutral wire. There is no getting around this.

Since we don't have a photo, we don't know what kind of wiring you have. If you have individual wires in conduit (tubing), you may be able to pull another wire through to provide the neutral. If not and you instead have a cable containing the wires, you will need to replace the cable to add the neutral. Code requires that associated current-carrying wires be in the same conduit or cable so you cannot just add an additional wire outside the cable.

Comment: For some reason I can’t add a photo or can’t figure it out I guess. Yes in North America. I assume it’s knob and tube wiring but would need to pull the box out to see what’s behind. They have a red and white wire that are attached with a wire nut to whatever is behind the wall.

Comment: To add a picture, Edit your question, then click the "mountain landscape" icon at the upper right of the edit box.

Comment: Got it thanks! I appreciate it

Comment: Is there any configuration that I could put a light switch and outlet here even if I have to modify the box

Comment: If those are the only wires you have, and those wires previously served a switch, then no you can't add an outlet without new wiring.

Comment: 'Is there any configuration that I could put a light switch and outlet here even if I have to modify the box"? NO; as explained by @DoxyLover in his (or her) answer, you do not have a grounded conductor (neutral). If you do not understand this concept I recommend doing a bit of basic electrical/house wiring research and get someone with more familiarity with electrical work to help you.